# Delete an entire row if date is less than 50 days of current date

Tags: shell, unix, awk, ksh

I need help to delete a row if date is older than n days at specified column.My file contains following. From the below file , I need to find out the entries less than 50 days old of current date in column 4 and delete the entire row.

```
ABC, 2017-02-03, 123, 2012-09-08   
BDC, 2017-01-01, 456, 2015-09-05    
Test, 2017-01-05, 789, 2017-02-03
```

My desired output is follows.

```
ABC, 2017-02-03, 123, 2012-09-08
BDC, 2017-01-01, 456, 2015-09-05
```

Note: I have an existing script and need to integrate this to the existing one.

Comment: Do you have `gawk` installed? can you check `which gawk`?

Comment: which gawk returned /bin/gawk

Comment: The date `2015-09-05` is in `YYYY-MM_DD` or `YYYY-DD-MM` format? which one follows the year, month or date?

Comment: YYYY-MM_DD.  sample is as follows., Also the variables are seperated by comma. like ABC,2017-02-03,123,2012-09-08

Comment: When providing sample dates, it's best to provide samples that cannot be misinterpreted. `02-03` could be Feb 3rd or Mar 2nd and `09-08` could be Sep 8th or Aug 9th. `02-23` on the other can can only be Feb 23 and `09-18` can only be Sep 18th and so would be much more useful samples. Every date you're provided so far in your question and comments is ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

you can leverage `date` command for this task, which will simplify the script

```
$ awk -v t=$(date -d"-50 day" +%Y-%m-%d) '$4<t' input > output
```

which will have this content in the output file

```
ABC, 2017-02-03, 123, 2012-09-08   
BDC, 2017-01-01, 456, 2015-09-05
```

replace input/output with your file names

Comment: Great answer. This is GNU date only though. For a POSIX version, use epoch time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `gawk` logic something like below,

```
gawk '
BEGIN {FS=OFS=",";date=strftime("%Y %m %d %H %M %S")}
{
    split($4, d, "-")
    epoch = mktime(d[1] " " d[2] " " d[3] " " "00" " " "00" " " "00")
    if ( ((mktime(date) - epoch)/86400 ) > 50) print
}' file
```

The idea is to use [`GNU Awk` string functions `strftime()` and `mtkime()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) for date conversion. The former produces a timestamp in `YYYY MM DD HH MM SS` format which `mktime` uses for conversion to `EPOCH` time.

Once the two times, i.e. the current timestamp (`date`) and `epoch` from `$4` in file are converted to `EPOCH`, the difference is divided by `86400` to get the differences in days and only those lines whose difference is greater `50` are printed.

Comment: Thanks Inian for your help, Can you tell me how to use this?? awk -f filename??

Comment: Sorry Inian, I do not get it. Should I mention the output filename in place of "file" ?? Also from where exactly it is reading the variable? Should I mention "gawk" also. I have very basic knowledge on this, Kindly help..

Comment: That creates an edge case where the current timestamp includes time of day today but the input timestamp doesn't so what does a "day" mean when being compared in seconds under those conditions? You should get rid of the seconds from the current date timestamp so you're comparing the same time of day for "now" to the input by using `date=strftime("%Y %m %d 0 0 0")`. Obviously for efficiency you should also be calling `mktime` on that once in the BEGIN section instead of for every input line and `" " "00" " " "00" " " "00"` should be just `" 0 0 0"`.

Comment: @Sunny1985 The input is coming from the file `file`. When your file is called `sun123` the last line will be `}' sun123`. Just try the commandline with `gawk` as given by Inian. When `gawk` is not found, you can try to replace that with `/usr/bin/gawk` or try `awk`. When you want the result in an outputfile, append `> an_outputfile` to the last line.